# How to do this in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Lets say that there are two variable, the value of the variable is taken from the users. That is:

```
a=0
b=1
c=a-b
```

For some cases i need the variable `c` to be always positive, is there is any method in Groovy to do this?

Comment: 1) How do you want to assure the value is positive? 2) Is this something Groovy specific? 3) Do you want the user to be informed that they can't enter a certain value? If not you could just use `if (c < 0)`, and the rest is the same for every other programming language.

Comment: I got an answer of what i want! i want `c` to be positive only(even if the calculation make it negative)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of options, depending on want behaviour you actually want when `c` is negative:

```
c = Math.abs(c) // -1 will become 1

c = Math.max(0,c) // -1 will become 0

// or it's an error condition
if( c < 0 ){
    tellUserToStopMessingAroundAndEnterTheCorrectValues()
    return
}
```